# Prove that $\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^n}-\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}<e$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

For all $n\in\mathbb N$ prove that:
$$\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^n}-\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}<e$$

We can rewrite it in the following form 
$$(n+2)\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n}-(n+1)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}<e$$ or
$$(n+1)\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}-n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}<e$$
and how should I proceed?

Comment: Maybee take logarithms and use derivatives and standard calculus methods.

Comment: @Ahmed S. Attaalla $e$ does not give.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Have you seen my answer below? I think mine is the complete proof. It actually partly cites your proof of convexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claude Leibovici's answer prove only that the proposition is true for sufficiently large rather than arbitrary positive $n$. Here is the complete proof with stronger result.

---

Let 
$$f(x):=x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x},\ x>0.$$ 
$$f'(x) = e^{x\ln(1+\frac1x)}\Big[1+x\Big(\ln\Big(1+\frac1x\Big)-\frac1{1+x}\Big)\Big].$$
$f$ increases since
$$\ln\Big(1+\frac1x\Big)=-\ln\Big(1-\frac1{1+x}\Big)>\frac1{1+x}$$
by Taylor expansion of the logarithmic function around $1$. Because [$f(x)$ is strictly convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2113636/64809), $1=f'(0)<f'(x)<f'(\infty)=e,\ \forall x\in (0,\infty)$.

So we conclude more than the required inequality
$$1<f(n)-f(n-1)<f(n+1)-f(n) = \int_n^{n+1}f'(x)dx<e,\ \forall n\ge 1.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! It quits that I was near this solution.

Comment: This is the proof, indeed ! Thanks for providing it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici and Michaeal Rozenberg: No worries. I am glad you both like it.

Answer (score 4):

*I do not know if this is a satisfactory answer for you.*

Consider $$A=\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^n}\qquad , \qquad B=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}$$ Take logarithms and expand as Taylor series for large values of $n$. This would lead to $$\log(A)=1+\log \left(n\right)+\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{3
   n^2}-\frac{13}{12 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ $$\log(B)=1+\log \left(n\right)-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{3
   n^2}-\frac{1}{4 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ Taylor again $$A=e^{\log(A)}=e n+\frac{e}{2}+\frac{11 e}{24 n}-\frac{43 e}{48
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$B=e^{\log(B)}=e n-\frac{e}{2}+\frac{11 e}{24 n}-\frac{7 e}{16
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ $$A-B=e-\frac{11 e}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: Beautiful way! Learned something. Thank you!

Comment: This only concludes the inequality for sufficiently large but not for arbitrary $n$. More accurate calculation is needed to draw the desired conclusion.

Comment: @Hans. I totally agree with you. I was hoping that my answer did precise that this was done for large values of $n$.

Comment: Please take a look at my proof of stronger result for arbitrary $n$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
    f(n) &= (n+2)(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^n - (n+1)(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n-1}\\
    &= (1+\frac{1}{n+1})^n + (n+1)((1+\frac{1}{n+1})^n - (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n-1})
    \rightarrow e,
\end{align*}
If $a(n) = n(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ then, because of [convexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4672151),
$(a(n+1) - a(n-1))/2 > a(n)$ and
$$
f(n+1) - f(n) = a(n+1) - 2a(n) - a(n-1) > 0.
$$
Since
$f(1)<e$ and the function is increasing it must approach the limit
from below so $f(n) < e$.