# Convexity of $x\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x,\ x\ge 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, exponential-function

This may turn out to be really simple but I do not see a quick way to the proof. How would one show $\displaystyle x\Big(1+\frac1x\Big)^x,\ x\ge 0$ is convex?

I derived the second derivative. It has a negative term. I suppose I could combine certain terms to make the negativeness disappear. But I hope there is a really clever way to see it right away.

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to show that $\log(f(x))$ is convex? this implies naturally thee convexity of $f(x)$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function

Comment: @tired, In here, $\log (f(x))$ is not convex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following answer is an compose of the comment of tired under the original question and [the answer of Michael Rozenberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2113438/267875). The quickest way at the end of the remark.

**Lemma 1.** If $f(x)$ for $x>0$ is convex and twice differentiable,  then $xf(\frac{1}{x})$ is convex for  $x>0$.

**Proof.** By a direct calculation $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2 (x f(\frac{1}{x}))}{\mathrm{d} x^2}  = \dfrac{f''\Big(\dfrac{1}{x}\Big)}{x^3}$. QED

**Lemma 2.** Let $f(x)$  be twice differentiable and positive for $x>0$. If $\ln f(x)$ is convex,  then $f(x)$ is convex.

**Proof.** By a direct calculation $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2 \ln f(x)}{\mathrm{d} x^2}  = \dfrac{f(x)f''(x)-[f'(x)]^2}{f^2(x)}$, and by noticing that $\ln f(x)$ is convex, we get 
$$
\dfrac{f(x)f''(x)-[f'(x)]^2}{f^2(x)} \ge 0.
$$
Since $f(x)$ is positive, 
$$
f''(x) \ge \dfrac{[f'(x)]^2}{f(x)}\ge 0.
$$
QED

**Proof of the convexity of $x(1+1/x)^x$.** By Lemma 1, we only need to show that $g(x)=(1+x)^{1/x}$ is convex. Then by Lemma 2, it is sufficient to prove that $\ln g(x) = \frac{1}{x}\ln (1+x)$ is convex.

Since 
$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2 \ln g(x)}{\mathrm{d} x^2}  = \frac{2 (x+1)^2 \log (x+1)-x (3 x+2)}{x^3 (x+1)^2},$$
we need to prove that 
$$
\log (x+1)-\frac{x (3 x+2)}{2 (x+1)^2}>0, 
$$
which can be easily followed from
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d} \Bigl(\log (x+1)-\frac{x (3 x+2)}{2 (x+1)^2}\Bigr)}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{x^2}{(x+1)^3} > 0
$$
and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\Big[\log (x+1)-\frac{x (3 x+2)}{2 (x+1)^2}\Big] = 0$. QED

**Remark.** For Lemma 1  see  [Convex function calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Convex_function_calculus),i.e.,

> If $f(x)$ is convex, then its perspective $\displaystyle
> > g(x,t)=tf\Big(\frac{x}{t}\Big)$ (whose domain is ${\displaystyle
> > \left\lbrace (x,t)\big|{\tfrac {x}{t}}\in {\text{Dom}}(f),t>0\right\rbrace
> > } \left\lbrace (x,t)\big|{\tfrac {x}{t}}\in
> > {\text{Dom}}(f),t>0\right\rbrace )$ is convex.

It seems that the above lemma is from probability which I do not familiar with. So I show Lemma 1 instead.  And for Lemma 2 see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function. If the problem comes from a textbook, I think the above is a clever way. If it comes from a real research, Michael Rozenberg's answer is good enough.  However, the most cunning way, which will return the result less then 1 second, I found is to type  the following code in Mathematica:

```
Minimize[{D[x (1 + 1/x)^x, {x, 2}], x > 0}, x]
```

Comment: I just  differentiated twice. I think, there is a mistake in your computations.

Comment: Most of calculations are by Mathematica， and I copied the outputs from the notebook. Could you show me which line is wrong？

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I'm happy to have enough reputations to add a comment. Wang's proof is so cool, then it can not be wrong ;-)

Comment: I did not like $\ln(x+1)>\frac{x(3x+2)}{2(x+1)^2}$

Comment: I did not like $\ln (x+1) > \frac{x(3x+2)}{2(x+1)^2}$ and $\ln (1+1/x) > \frac{\sqrt{x^2+3x+1}-1}{x(x+1)}$ both. But they are correct bothly.

Comment: Elegant proof. I like it.

Comment: tres bien...more or less what i had in mind (+1)

Comment: @wangtwo lemma 2, is wrong. Convexity of $\text{log}[f(x)]$ does not imply convexity of $f(x)$.

Comment: @kaka I'v added more details for the proof of Lemma 2. In fact it is not my lemma, it comes from the wiki page. I just give a proof for the convenience of readers.

Comment: What is the last Mathematica script for? If it is to show the convexity of the original function, plotting its graph is more convincing.

Comment: @Hans it is used for calculating the minimum value of the second derivative of $x(1+1/x)^x$ for $x>0$. And the output shows the minimum is not achieved, but the function convergences to 0 as $x \to +\infinity$.

Comment: Sure, but all it says is that the second derivative is positive. But how does that help with the proof?

Comment: @wangtwo I was wrong. Lemma 2 is correct. Since $e^{\text{log}f(x)}=f(x)$  and we know $e^{g(x)}$ is convex if $g(x)$ is convex. Q.E.D

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg and wangtwo: I came up with an elegant proof for the convexity of $\frac{\ln(1+x)}x$. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x)=x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$, where $x>0$.

Hence,
$$f''(x)=\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\left(x(x+1)^2\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+2(x+1)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-x-3\right)}{(x+1)^2}.$$
Thus, we need to prove that 
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)>\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3x+1}-1}{x(x+1)}.$$
Let $g(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3x+1}-1}{x(x+1)}.$

Hence, $$g'(x)=\frac{2x^3+9x^2+7x+2-2\sqrt{(x^2+3x+1)^3}}{2x^2(x+1)^2\sqrt{x^2+3x+1}}=$$
$$=-\frac{11x^3+46x^2+35x+8}{2x(x+1)^2\sqrt{x^2+3x+1}\left(2x^3+9x^2+7x+2+2\sqrt{(x^2+3x+1)^3}\right)}<0,$$
which says that $g(x)>\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}g(x)=0$ and we are done!

Comment: Nice proof. +1. Perseverance in calculation pays off. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add to the elegant proof of @wangtwo, and remedy the only blemish of an ugly proof of the convexity of $\frac{\ln(1+x)}x$ in a piece of otherwise perfect work. Here is an elegant replacement.
$$\frac{\ln(1+x)}x=\int_0^1 \frac1{1+xt}dt$$
is convex since the integrand is convex with respect to $x$.

---

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2593951/64809) is a closely related problem and my own solution as mentioned by @wangtwo in his comment below.

Comment: @Hans Your proof is very nice, and I want gain more information from your
proof. So I search for "parameter integral convex function", and found a
treasure that is Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe's textbook
Convex Optimization (Cambridge University Press,
Cambridge, 2004. xiv+716 pp. ISBN: 0-521-83378-7).  The pdf version of book can be downloaded from Prof. Boyd's homepage
https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/. In page 79 of the book, the
authors introduce a similar idea as your post in
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2593913/64809

Comment: All I learned is the following:
Though convexity is an elementary concept in the first year calculus, it
is much better to read an advanced textbook before proving convexity.

Comment: @wangtwo: Thank you for the book reference. It is indeed a treasure. I agree with your sentiment. It is the kind of concept that is simple yet has many variations and applications that is the most profound.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
&f''(x)\\&= (\frac{1}{x}+ 1)^x \frac{(-x + x (x + 1)^2 \log^2(\frac{1}{x} + 1) + 2 (x + 1) \log(\frac{1}{x} + 1) - 3)}{(x + 1)^2}\\
&\propto
-x + x (x + 1)^2 \log^2(\frac{1}{x} + 1) + 2 (x + 1) \log(\frac{1}{x} + 1) - 3\\
&=
(x + 1)\log(\frac{1}{x} + 1)\Big(2+ x (x + 1)\log(\frac{1}{x}+1)\Big) - (3+x)\\
&\geq
2\frac{x+1}{2x+1}\Big(2+ x 2\frac{x+1}{2x+1}\Big) - (3+x)\\
&=
4\frac{x+1}{(2x+1)^2}\Big(2x+1+x^2+ x\Big) - (3+x)
=\frac{3x+1}{(2x+1)^2}\geq0.
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $\log(1+\frac{1}{x}) \geq \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{2}}$.