# Elegant proof of convexity

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality, convex-analysis, elementary-functions

I am seeking an elegant way to prove the concavity with respect to $x$ of 
$$f(x,t,a):=\Big(1-\frac1{(1+x)^t}\Big)\Big(1-\frac ax\Big), \quad x\ge0,\; t>0,\; a>0.$$

I put up my mundane proof as an answer below.

Comment: Interesting - where did the function come from?

Comment: @max_zorn: This is the payoff of a payer swaption with respect to the swap rate $x$ before having the positive filter operator $(\cdot)_+$ applied to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found an elegant proof:

$$g(x,t):=\frac1x\Big(1-\frac1{(1+x)^t}\Big)=t\int_0^1\frac1{(1+\zeta x)^{t+1}}\,d\zeta$$
is convex with respect to $x$ since the integrand is. So $-ag(x,t)$ is concave. As $h(x,t):=1-\frac1{(1+x)^t}$ is concave also with respect to $x$, so is $f(x,t,a)=h(x,t)-ag(x,t)$.

---

Here is the proposition I used in the above proof.

> Proposition: Function $h(x,t)$ is convex in $x$ and integrable on $t\in[0,1]$. $I(x):=\int_0^1h(x,t)dt$ is convex.

Proof: $\forall \lambda\in[0,1]$,
\begin{align}
I(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)&=\int_0^1h\big(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y,t\big)\,dt \\
&\le \int_0^1\big(\lambda h(x,t)+(1-\lambda)h(y,t)\big)\,dt \\ &=\lambda\int_0^1h(x,t)dt+(1-\lambda)\int_0^1h(y,t)\,dt \\
&= \lambda I(x)+(1-\lambda)I(y). 
\end{align}
So $I$ is convex.

Comment: "is convex with respect to $x$ since the integrand is" : could you give the result you use here ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: I just added a proof of my proposition of convexity. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks, @Hans, it is now very clear.

Comment: Very nice proof!

Comment: Thanks, @max_zorn.

Comment: Nice and clean (+1)

Comment: Thank you, @BAI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my mundane proof I mentioned in the question:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x,t,a) = -t(1+t)(1+x)^{-2-t}-2a \frac{(1+x)^{2+t}-(2+t) x \big(1+\frac{1+t}2x\big)-1}{x^3(1+x)^{2+t}}.
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{2+t}&=1+(2+t)x+\frac{(2+t)(1+t)}2x^2+\frac{(2+t)(1+t)t}2\int_0^x(x-y)^2(1+y)^{t-1}dy \quad \text{(Taylor expansion)} \\
&>1+(2+t)x+\frac{(2+t)(1+t)}2x^2.
\end{align}
So $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x,t,a)<0$$
and $f(x,t,a)$ is concave with respect to $x$.